# Maven - copy resource to specific location in jar

Tags: java, maven

I want to copy a resource inside my project into my jar to a specific folder while building.
I use this code inside my `pom.xml`:

```
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/locale</directory>
</resource>
```

to copy all the files inside the locale directory to my jar. But the files are all copied to the root directory of the jar file, not inside a `locale` folder.

Is it possible to copy resources with Maven to a specific location inside the exported jar file?

Comment: Move the files into `src/main/resources/locale` than they will automatically be within `locale` folder.

Comment: @khmarbaise The problem is I don't want to use src/main  folder structure but Tunaki answered my question already.

Comment: What is a reason not to follow the convention?

Comment: @khmarbaise I just don't like the structure. I think the default java structure is more clear. And I don't think it is really neccessary to follow these rules.

Comment: Not following these conventions is more like working against Maven rather than with it. If you'd followed it it probably wouldn't have been necessary to even ask this question here.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Of course you are right but if it should not be possible, there would not be such an option. Tunakis method worked well, because maven is not meant to organize your folder structure but your dependencies.

Comment: That's just half right. Maven manages dependencies, right. A resource is not a dependency. Another – important – part of Maven is managing your entire build process. A build process needs files located in well-defined folders. Your turn. ;)

Comment: @GeroldBroser Well, that's true, but being well organized is always important, also in non-maven projects and if you always organize your folder structure the same way, it is better than following different rules in different projects. Your turn ^^

Comment: Maven is all about convention over configuration. If you adhere to the conventions of Maven, you will find that your pom.xml will be much simpler, but also that it will be much simpler for someone _else_ to understand your build process. But again, Maven is very flexible and allows you to do pretty much what you want. The reason is that there is a fine line between adhering to a convention and following it blindly.

Comment: @Tunaki +1, except the last sentence. This is different with different individuals, IMHO. If you know what you are doing and why there's very few potential for said blindness at all.

Comment: @Tunaki Maybe you are right, adhering it completely is not the right way, but I always put my locale folder to the root directory, in every project. Perhaps it would be better to just follow these rules, and I mostly follow them but there are still some things which I just don't want to accept the "maven" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [`targetPath`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) attribute. Quoting the Maven reference:

> targetPath: Specifies the directory structure to place the set of resources from a build. Target path defaults to the base directory. A commonly specified target path for resources that will be packaged in a JAR is META-INF.

```
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/locale</directory>
    <targetPath>locale</targetPath>
</resource>
```